# Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet_Protection' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I use PHPexcel to read excel data in a CodeIgniter.
It works fine in localhost.
Whenever I upload it to live server an error message comes up like this.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered

```
Type: Error

Message: Class 'PHPExcel_Worksheet_Protection' not found

Filename: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

Line Number: 356

Backtrace:

File: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/application/third_party/PHPExcel.php
Line: 371
Function: __construct

File: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/application/libraries/Excel.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/application/controllers/MainController.php
Line: 132
Function: library

File: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/application/controllers/MainController.php
Line: 106
Function: readExcel

File: /home/customer/www/mail.escaperoommarketer.com/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Does anybody know why this error occurred and what is the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Composer? Did you ran it?

Comment: No. it works well in localhost and another live server. When i upload this to my new server in siteground this error comes up.

Comment: Look for the class in the `third_party` folder and see if its present.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. protection class file is not there. i upload this file and now it;s work properly.